# Set default timezone for mysql client

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database that stores time in UTC. However, when I connect to it using MySQL Workbench I would like to see time in PST. I know I can use tz_convert to convert individual columns to PST. I was wondering is there any way I set the entire client session to a timezone so that I don't have to put tz_convert over every individual time columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your column has to be of the type TIMESTAMP to be automatically converted to your local timestamp. As written in [10.6 MySQL Server Time Zone Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html):

> The current session time zone setting affects display and storage of time values that are zone-sensitive. This includes the values displayed by functions such as NOW() or CURTIME(), and values stored in and retrieved from TIMESTAMP columns. Values for TIMESTAMP columns are converted from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.

However, it does not work for DATE, TIME or DATETIME:

> The current time zone setting does not affect values displayed by functions such as UTC_TIMESTAMP() or values in DATE, TIME, or DATETIME columns. Nor are values in those data types stored in UTC; the time zone applies for them only when converting from TIMESTAMP values. If you want locale-specific arithmetic for DATE, TIME, or DATETIME values, convert them to UTC, perform the arithmetic, and then convert back.